# "build" function for Python code is not active in webots

Tags: python, webots

I am a new user to webots. I want to practise and write my code in Python, but the "build" icon in webots is not active (and I cannot build my code through "Build" in menu in the top bar, because it is inactive too.
I followed the instructions published in webots documentation, but I still cannot build any of my projects or example controllers, although I can launch sample python world and controllers. At the same time, I can build projects written in C.
I have Python 3.7 installed.
Could you please give me a hint what should I do to be able to build python projects in webots?

"build the current project" and "remove intermediate build files icons" are not active:

[image]

EDIT: I tried reinstalling Python 3.7 and tried to run webots with Python 3.8. I installed all recommended libraries. I also reinstalled webots.

Comment: better for you to tell us what you have tried so far and what the results were.   we can then advise what might be the next step to fix your issue.

Comment: I tried reinstalling Python 3.7 and tried to run webots with Python 3.8. I installed all recommended libraries. I also reinstalled webots.

Answer (score 2):

Python is an interpreted language: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language

It therefore doesn't need to be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **pause the simulation** and **start it from the beginning** after saving the new updated code in **EPuckGoForward.py** and ensure that it has a virtual time of 0.

To do this **Reload the current world** and restart the simulation.
[check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2lWq.png)